# Do I need to pass through immigration in CDG?

Tags: transit, cdg

I'm travelling from Canada to Russia, connecting in Paris CDG airport.
The inbound and outbound flights are both in terminal 2 (2C and 2E) same airline (air france).

Looking at the [this](http://easycdg.com/passenger-information/connecting-flight-connections-paris-cdg-airport/transit-terminal-2c/):

[image]

It seems I need to take the bus and I see a "Police" section after that.

I'm not entering the Schengen area. Do I need to pass through immigration and have a visa?
Or do the buses operate within the transit area?

Comment: Note that citizens of some countries need a visa even if they stay airside (there are exceptions based on other visas they may hold).

Comment: Thank you @jcaron
Where can I see that information?
I hold an Iranian passport but I do have a valid Canadian visa and resident permit.

Comment: https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/airport-transit-visa Holders of Iranian passports require and airport transit visa, but holders of a valid Canadian visa are exempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [forum post](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/15716412-post2.html) outlines a 2E to 2C trip:

1. Disembark and follow the signs for "Correspondances/Flight Transfers."
2. You will pass some info desks. These agents tend to be very helpful and should be your first stop if you have questions and/or need onward boarding passes printed. Greet them with "Bonjour," switch to English, and they'll generally treat you well.
3. Walk on to the bus stop, clearly marked as "2A/2B/2C/2D/2F". There will be a listing of upcoming buses on a monitor. Just get on the first one that shows a stop at 2C. Don't bother waiting for the express, as it's the difference between 0 and 1 stops. There's an agent at the bus stop who kind of tries to look at people's boarding passes and get them on the right bus.
4. Get off at 2C. Like I said, it's either next stop or 1 stop later. You're not even on the bus 5 minutes.
5. Pass security.
6. Walk up a half-flight of stairs, and you're standing in 2C. Don't get your rollaboard-bag all ready to roll, as you really do need to walk the half-flight of stairs. There's prob an elevator somewhere, but I didn't see it.

Another [post](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/9289405-post3.html) in the other direction mentions explicitly you need to pass security:

> take the airside bus that goes from 2C, to 2A, 2B, 2F and then S3, one 2E's boarding areas, and finally 2E's main boarding area; as the bus circles around CDG2 clockwise, you have the longest possible airside transfer. You will not go through any immigration check, but you will need to clear security when entering the boarding area.

Answer (score 3):

The source of your image contains some conditional text below the image:

> – Proceed to your boarding gate.*
>
> * Via Immigration/Passport control if you are transferring to a Schengen flight at terminal 2D or 2F.

Since you're transferring to a non-Schengen flight at terminal 2E, the immigration checkpoint does not apply to you.