# Airside transfer at Paris CDG

Tags: airport-transfer, paris, cdg

I will be transferring at Paris CDG aeroport, between two different airline partners, having a single ticket(my bags are checked-in, won’t have to leave the airside).
But I will land at T2E, and will have to transfer to T2A.

*Is it possible to transfer airside from T2E to T2A at Paris CDG Aéroport without passing through border control or customs?*

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate:  [Do I need to pass through immigration in CDG?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138802/)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert hrmm the answer there is outdated, they shuffled the shuttles. And also that was of different terminals.

Comment: I'm curious, what are your incoming and outgoing flights? T2E/T2A connections are not very common.

Comment: @jcaron, gulf air till Paris, then Air canada. Both are interline partners and Gulf air told me they’ll check the baggage through end destination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [shuttles](https://www.parisaeroport.fr/en/passengers/access/paris-charles-de-gaulle/inter-terminal-shuttles), you want the blue one. You definitely won't need to pass immigration/customs but you might need to pass security, likely before boarding the shuttle

[image: Blue shuttle]

Comment: Thanks a lot @chx, I had seen this but had no idea if this includes passing through immigration. Thanks again.

Comment: You not finding some information is no fault of yours. There's a reason CDG is constantly featured on top 10 worst airport lists. I have a _very_ hard time properly sourcing my claim nonetheless this is so based on many trip reports and also the page splitting between the land side and the air side shuttles.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, i was hoping for help from someone like you who had traveled and gone through this path at cdg, and you helped me very well sir. I was stressed out if I had to go through immigration I would have to apply for a visa, relieved from that issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JS Note that for some nationalities, you need a transit visa even if you do not go through immigration. What is your citizenship?

Comment: @jcaron I’m an Indian citizen, and hold valid residence of Canada, so I’ll be exempted from that requirement. Thanks a lot for presenting a very valid point.

Comment: One more stupid question about this trip I would want to ask is, will the first airline be able to present the boarding passes for all legs in this trip? @chx thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The official CDG website is really soooo bad.

Comment: @JS If they can check you through, they should be able to deliver all boarding passes, but it can happen that it's not possible for some reason (mostly if the time between check-in and the departure of the second flight is beyond a certain limit). In that case you should be able to get the further boarding passes from a transfer desk airside.

Comment: @jcaron thanks a lot sir, I have been relieved from all the confusion.